# How can I plot a radius of all reachable points with pathfinding for a Mob?

Tags: 2d, ai, path-finding, rpg

I am designing a tactical turn based game.  The maps are 2d, but do have varying level-layers and blocking objects/terrain.  I'm looking for an algorithm for pathfinding which will allow me to show an opaque shape representing all of the possible max-distance pixels that a mob can move to, knowing the mob's max pixel distance.

Any thoughts on this, or do I just need to write a good pathfinding algorithm and use it to find the cutoff points for any direction in which an obstacle exists?

Comment: 1) Does your game feature tile-based movement? Your question seems to imply it doesn't, since you're talking about pixels. 2) Do you already have a specific path finding algorithm in place which plans a path to a target location for a given mob? You will need this anyway, and you might be able to reuse it for this problem. Specifying it might make answering your question easier.

Comment: 1)  No, at this point, I'm letting the player / mobs move pixel-by-pixel, even though the maps are laid out in tile fashion.  2) I haven't implemented any path-finding, yet, no, and you're right - I have to do that, anyway, so I may as well make it a priority, first, and just allow characters to do something like move anywhere inside of their radius on the horizontal axis in the meantime.

Comment: Well, then every pixel is a tile.

Comment: You may also be interested in how far enemies can attack from those tiles, the algorithm for that is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638583/algorithm-for-finding-spaces-to-attack-target-within-move-attack-area-on-a-2d-gr

Answer (score 6):

Start of with the simplest pathfinding algorithm (I believe) [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search):
[image: bfs pathfinding]

This is actually a very good algorithm if you want to find the best possible path, especially if various tiles have different movement ratios (how much movement points it costs to enter/leave the tile, e.g. mountain could take 3 points and road only 1/3). Because you have a limited movement, your BFS will end pretty quickly, most probably letting you calculate paths for one unit in a single frame without FPS drop below 60.

For an algorithm below I'll assume a little harder scenario, where there are various movement costs of tiles.

**Here's the recipe:**:
You will need:

- the value representing how far you can go, named `movement_points`
- one dictionary of tile:movement_points_to_reach_it pairs named `costs`
- one list of `tiles_to_check`
- one list of `tiles_being_checked`
- starting tile, for which you check possible paths, let's name the tile a `hero`.

Let's make the cake:

1. Add `hero` to `tiles_to_check`
2. Initialize boolean `changed` variable with `true`
3. Start While (changed) loop.

   1. `changed = false;`
   2. `tiles_being_checked = tiles_to_check;`
   3. Assign new Array to `tiles_to_check`.
   4. Iterate through all `tiles_being_checked`

      - iterate through all tiles surrounding the current tile being checked and run a `processTile` function:
      - `t=tiles_being_checked[i]; for(x=t.x-1; x<=t.x+1; x++) for(y=t.y-1; y<=t.y+1; y++) if (x!=t.x || y!=t.y) processTile(t, x, y)`

**In processTile(tile, x, y) do:**

1. `next_tile = world_grid[x][y];`
2. Check if `next_tile` is passable, e.g. it's not a water tile. (if yes, return)
3. Check the cost of moving from `tile` to the `next_tile` and save it as `cost`; (take care of if it's diagonal movement - multiply by square root of 2 - and what's this/next tile's movement cost.
4. `total_cost = costs[tile] + cost;`
5. **Check if there are enough movement points to reach it:** `if (total_cost > movement_points) return;`
6. Check if there already exists this tile (as a key) in your `costs` dictionary, and if yes, check if you already found a better or equal way for this tile: `if (costs[next_tile] <= total_cost) return`
7. If not, write the new cost `costs[next_tile] = total_cost`
8. add `next_tile` to `tiles_to_check`
9. set `changed = true`.

**In the end use `costs` dictionary to check if a tile can be reached** by given movement points (it exists as a key in the dictionary) and to check how much movement points it will cost. To check for the path:

1. Choose a destination tile (that can be reached)
2. Set `currentX  = tile.x; currentY = tile.y;`
3. Set `cost = MAX_INT;`
4. Create an Array of tiles `path = new Array ();`
5. start `while ( currentX != startTile.x || currentY != startTile.y )` loop.

   1. Iterate through neighboring tiles...
   2. ... and if a given neighboring tile, let's name it a `nTile` has lower cost than current: `if (costs[nTile] < cost) { cost = costs[nTile]; currentX=nTile.x; currentY=nTile.y;`
6. Reverse the array.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look this algorithm over and see if I can't implement it, at least for AI path-finding, if not for the solution to this particular issue.

Comment: Finished the answer. Click here to see what changed: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/43310/revisions

Comment: Why does the tile to the top right of the smiley face have a distance of 1 instead of 2?

Comment: @Adam I've spotted that too, that's most probably a mistake.

Comment: Well, ideally you'd at least alternate between 1,2 distance for diagonal paths, right?  Since it's basically 1.44 * normal distance to move diagonally?

Comment: @PugWrath 1.4142... But in some games it's just 1

Comment: This is probably the best pseudocode example I've ever seen!

Comment: Regardless of how good the pseudocode is, it's worse than code, took me close to 4 hours to implement and debug that

Comment: @AlexStone Sorry! Maybe you could share your codez?